# How can i load page with fancybox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I know how to use fancybox popup, normally, which means making an link and click open the fancybox.

But the requirement is, if the user presses a link without logging in,

it has to refresh the page with the popup already opened.

Is this possible in fancybox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery click trigger

**Script**

```
        $("#autostart").fancybox().trigger('click');
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="autostart" style="display:none" href="select_category.html" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"></a>
```

Comment: sorry for the late check :)